# Missing commands for Magento command line

Tags: magento2, command-line

Whenever I run the common commands I get this and similarly named errors:

```
    [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.
```

Im using Magento 2.2.5

Comment: In terminal other command work like cache clear and indexing ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the resolution was to compile: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. If that seems to do nothing or acts like it completes part of the way through, try increasing your memory limit: `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile`.
Once I had compiled, I could set the deploy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try by enabling developer mode

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Answer (score 0):

Run Following steps to check & then try again:

1. Run **“composer install”** in magento root
2. please use the **-v** or **-vv** option in the command line for debug information.
3. If an extension has no `etc/module.xml` file then `bin/magento` fails.
4. If a `composer.json` has a syntax error.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, remove generated directory and execute

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

provide permission 777 to generated directory.

now please check your Magento commands

Answer (score 0):

Not having a proper content in `app/etc/env.php` / missing the default db connection array node can also cause the `deploy:mode` command to be missing from `bin/magento`, along with many other commands. Check that you have a properly defined .env file, comparing to `.env.dist`. The behaviour of missing commands, can be replicated quickly (at least on Magento 2.3.6) by emptying `.env` file as such

```
<?php
    return [
];
```

or removing just the `default` node from the `db`/`connection` node

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
```

in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Just flush your redis cache. This is the problem.

```
redis-cli FLUSHALL
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be a permission issue. You can run these  commands under your Magento directory :

**sudo chmod 775 -R ./generated/ ./var/ ./pub/**

Comment: It did not.  I got this error: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan i updated my answer , you can check it

Comment: Never give permission like above,because it should be like sudo chmod 777 -R  var/

Comment: Please put slash after var. don't use it before